# How to login to phppgadmin

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, phppgadmin

Ok,

My first day with postgresql.

I've downloaded and installed postgresql (to Windows), and it asked me to set a password (say: 1234).

Then I downloaded phppgadmin, and trying to login to pgadmin.

I tried

```
root:1234

postgres:1234
```

I can't login and also get the following php error from pgadmin

```
( ! ) Strict standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\wamp\www\phpPgAdmin-5.0.4\classes\database\Connection.php on line 23
```

Comment: Start with the bundled PgAdmin-III tool, or using `psql` (the PostgreSQL command prompt) from the Start menu. See the PostgreSQL tutorial. Once you're OK with those consider other tools. As for login, "root" is wrong for sure; the default user is `postgres` - but this looks like an issue in PHPPgAdmin where it doesn't appear to like running under PHP strict mode.

Comment: You write "pgadmin" where you mean "PostgreSQL"? `pgAdmin` is the bundled GUI (native program). `phpPgAdmin` is another GUI (web-based).

Comment: yeah, sorry, what I meant was phpPgAdmin. Following Craig's advice, I began to use pgadmin now.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

Open C:\wamp\www\phpPgAdmin-5.0.4\classes\database\Connection.php and remove the '&' on line 23 
and try it. 
You might have another error in C:\wamp\apps\phpPgAdmin-5.0.4\redirect.php on line 14 then replace

```
parse_str(value(url($url['url'], $url['urlvars']), $_REQUEST), $vars);
```

by

```
$href = url($url['url'], $url['urlvars']);

$val = value($href, $_REQUEST);

parse_str($val, $vars);
```

voila